# Latex forms: Place label on the right side of checkbox

Tags: pdftex, forms

Is there a way to display a checkbox's label on the right side? By default it is always on the left side.

I didn't find any parameter for this in the [documentation](http://www2.washjeff.edu/users/rhigginbottom/latex/resources/hyperref-manual.pdf).

Thanks in advance!

As the system requests a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\CheckBox{Test}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

My question is: How can I get the label on the right side of the clickable chekbox.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. And when linking to a manual also mention the name of the manual and link preferably to the CTAN document.

Comment: How about `\CheckBox{}\ Test` ?

Comment: That is definitly an option, I have tried so far. I thought there might be a prettier solution.

Comment: Related [How do I get choice radio box on the left side of text using hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404819/124842)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\CheckBox` internally uses the `\LayoutCheckField` to layout the items. The default, taken from `hyperref.sty` is:

```
\def\LayoutCheckField#1#2{% label, field
  #1 #2%
}
```

you can invert the order of the label and the field (swap `#1` and `#2`):

```
\def\LayoutCheckField#1#2{% label, field
  #2 #1%
}
```

Working example (copying Steven's layout :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\CheckBox{Test}
\end{Form}
\def\LayoutCheckField#1#2{% label, field
  #2 #1%
}

\medskip
\begin{Form}
\CheckBox{Test}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This, of course, is the proper approach.  +1

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the 2nd box to show up in an Adobe viewer, something had to be added to the argument (interestingly, `\mbox{}` did not work`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\CheckBox{Test}\medskip

\CheckBox{\ \unskip}\ Test
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

After clicking:

[image]